# How do I find the limit of the function?

Tags: calculus

How do I find the limit for the function $(1 + h)^{\frac{1}{h}}$ as $h$ goes to $0$? I do not know where to start. We just started using Logs.

Comment: what can you use?

Comment: Have you learned the formal definition of limits with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ or do you just want an intuitive argument?  It would be a little surprising if you have formally learned limits before logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$(1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e^{\frac{1}{h} \ln{(1+h)}}$$

So what is the limit $\frac{1}{h}\ln{(1+h)}$ as $h \to 0$?

Take  the function $f(h)=\ln(1+h)$ and we have $f(0)=0$

Then $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+h)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=f'(0)=1$$

Thus the general limit is $e$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\space \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\space {\frac{1}{h}}={\infty}\implies\space\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\space(1 + h)^{\frac{1}{h}}=(1+{\frac{1}{\infty}})^{\infty}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\space(1+\frac{1}{x})^x=e
$$